# Cannot generate sitemap for a site?

Tags: magento, sitemap

I have been trying to generate a sitemap for my site, I have used several 3rd party tools but none of them were successful,They either give an error or doesn't generate a proper sitemap and just show a single line . Here is my site btw: https://www.mightyhealthy.com/

Comment: Which sitemap? The user friendly one or the search engine friendly one? Magento generates both. If you're trying to generate one with a third party software by crawling the site, you're going to be disappointed. A bogged mess with a bazillion links, most of which will be redundant or outright failure as it hits 100,000+ links and falls flat on its face (which you're experiencing) vs. a simple cron job every night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the below url

```
/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/
```

it is magento's default sitemap

The url for your store will be as mention below

```
https://www.mightyhealthy.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/
```